# Magento 2 : How to update qty and stock status using API for multiple products?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api

How to update qty and stock status using API for multiple products in Magento 2?

We are doing ERP integration with Magento 2 and we need to update qty and stock status.

in magento 1 we had `catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate`  Soap API for update.

I have search in magento 2 API and found below:

```
catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1
PUT /V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/{itemId}

 
catalogProductRepositoryV1
PUT /V1/products/{sku}
```

But they only work for a single SKU.

What is the equivalent of `catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate` in Magento 2 API, Where we can pass an array of SKU for update qty and stock

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using Magento 2.3.x version you should be able to use the MSI API's ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/modules/inventory/manage-source-items.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this [bulk endpoints](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/bulk-endpoints.html)

> Bulk API endpoints differ from other REST endpoints in that they combine multiple calls of the same type into an array and execute them as a single request. The endpoint handler splits the array into individual entities and writes them as separate messages to the message queue.

To call a bulk endpoint, add the prefix /async/bulk before the /V1 of the asynchronous endpoint route. For example:

```
POST /async/bulk/V1/products
POST /async/bulk/V1/customers
```

Endpoint routes that contain input parameters require additional changes. For example, PUT /V1/products/:sku/media/:entryId contains the :SKU and :entryId input parameters. The route of a bulk request cannot contain input parameters, so you must change the route so that it does not contain any. To do this, replace the colon (:) with by and change the first letter of the parameter to uppercase.

> PUT /V1/products/:sku/media/:entryId   ->   PUT async/bulk/V1/products/bySku/media/byEntryId

it means your request join data should contain **entry_id** and **SKU** for each product.

### Updates:

I have tried the below and it is working fine for me, before trying the below you should install [rabbitmq](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html) and add queue configuration in **app/etc/env.php**

e.g) env.php

```
'queue' => [
'amqp' => [
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '5672',
  'user' => 'bilal',
  'password' => 'password',
  'virtualhost' => '/'
 ],
]
```

> PUT http://127.0.0.1/m234/rest/all/async/bulk/V1/products/bySku

**Request data:**

```
[
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "sku1",
    "name": "Product1",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "price":10,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "extension_attributes": {
      "stock_item": {
      "item_id": 3072,
      "product_id": 3073,
      "stock_id": 1,
      "qty": 20,
      "is_in_stock": true
      }
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "part_number",
        "value": "1234"
      }
    ]    
  }
},
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "3483",
    "name": "Product2",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "price":20,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "extension_attributes": {
      "stock_item": {
        "item_id": 3071,
        "product_id": 3072,
        "stock_id": 1,
        "qty": 10,
        "is_in_stock": true
      }
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "part_number",
        "value": "1234"
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

**Response**

```
{
    "bulk_uuid": "eda7899f-d00b-4d0a-b6f9-77fea3296f4d",
    "request_items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "data_hash": "986765adeb0b00b03997159b84b627f5c5eda5e281b52dc34d61446cc496ebf3",
            "status": "accepted"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "data_hash": "3ae299b09bd30686772ee24214b482d88776f49f68ce804b1e78dfc4c1d19802",
            "status": "accepted"
        }
    ],
    "errors": false
}
```

If cron configured, it will automatically trigger otherwise you need to run the below command manually to trigger the queue

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all
```

You can check this queue status in Magento **admin -> System -> Bulk Action Log** with the above response **bulk_uuid** (eda7899f-d00b-4d0a-b6f9-77fea3296f4d) Easy for your reference: https://nimb.ws/qnA6oY

Comment: Thank you for your answer. that means `rest/V1/products/001-main/stockItems/1` will be 
`rest/async/bulk/V1/products/bySku/stockItems/byEntryId` for bulk update ?

Comment: it should be rest/async/bulk/V1/products/bySku/stockItems/byItemId and the item_id should exist in the request data.

Comment: I change as per your comment and pass parameter as `[
{"stockItem":{
 "sku":"001-main",
 "qty":500,
 "item_id":1
 }
},
{"stockItem":{
 "sku":"BARLIQUORTESTSHOT",
 "qty":500,
 "item_id":1
 }
}
]'

Comment: but i am getting `"message": "Request does not match any route."` error

Comment: one more thin in swagger i can only see get method for `catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1`.

Comment: I can see the put method in swagger https://nimb.ws/9vbcWJ have you apply the bearer token in swagger

Comment: try with this url rest/async/bulk/V1/products/byProductSku/stockItems/byItemId and product_sku and item_id should be available in the request data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107873/discussion-between-pawan-and-bilal-usean).

Answer (score 1):

You must use this endpoint.

```
/rest/default/V1/inventory/source-items
```

To find the proper endpoint, I tested lots of endpoints including async/bulk/V1/products... but it's a unique solution for multiple products.

If you need more, I will share the full code package which I used for a real store

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
PUT /V1/products/byProductSku/stockItems/byItemId
```

with data as follows:

```
[
    {
        "product_sku": "BLA_BLA",
        "stockItem": {
            "item_id": 1234,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "is_qty_decimal": true,
            "qty": 1000
        }
    }
]
```

Notice that I have attributes `product_sku` and `item_id` in the payload.