# Magento 2 Bulk Product Update via API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, magento2.4.4

I'm trying to achieve a bulk update of products via the Magento (2.4.4) API. I've been following a guide here [Magento 2 : How to update qty and stock status using API for multiple products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312435/magento-2-how-to-update-qty-and-stock-status-using-api-for-multiple-products/312438#312438?s=78c558924c554fe0b03a9821043a99ba)

However, It seems somewhat counter intuitive. Individual products can be updated via a simple call to the **/rest/all/V1/products/sku** endpoint just by specifying the SKU but with the bulk update the article suggests that the endpoint **/rest/all/async/bulk/V1/products/byProductSku/stockItems/byItemId**
must be used. I therefore need to specify the ItemId of the sku in the request and to do this I have to get each individual sku and read the response to retrieve the id.. I have MSI modules disabled as it's a complete pain..

Is there an endpoint that can handle bulk requests by just specifying only the sku? ( I've tried **/rest/all/async/bulk/V1/products/bySku**  no joy..)

keep getting  an internal server error response

Comment: potentially an issue with 2.4.4 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35348

Comment: tried this fix https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/35347#pullrequestreview-1271811814 but still kicks back a bad request error?

Comment: c# escaped example json  "[
  {
    \"product\": {
      \"sku\": \"1234\",
      \"price\": 12.99,
      \"extension_attributes\": {
        \"stock_item\": {
          \"qty\": 1.0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    \"product\": {
      \"sku\": \"123456\",
      \"price\": 97.99,
      \"extension_attributes\": {
        \"stock_item\": {
          \"qty\": 3.0
        }
      }
    }
  }
]"

Comment: Bad Request was caused by Missing RabbitMQ.. Installed that and added queue configuration to env.php and up & running